# pool timer requires common wire - pump does not - how to wire in timer w/ common to serve pump w/o common?

Tags: wiring, pump, pool, timer

My older Intermatic RC2343PT timer requires a common wire to function, however my new 1.5 HP 230v 2-speed Pentair pump does not require common wire and would be powered through 20a tandem GFI breaker, so a common wire cannot be added to the circuit. Is it possible to interconnect timer and pump or must I get another type of timer that is compatible with the tandem GFI breaker? (Intermatic technician indicated they do not offer a timer w/o common wire that would also connect to an ionizer and air switch).

Comment: When you say "Common" do you mean "common" off the timer labeling.... or do you mean "Neutral"?  They are not the same thing.  Neutral is not "common", common is a hot line actually.  *I say that because the device instructions refer to "common" and "neutral" separately, for totally different functions, so the distinction is very important and likely to mislead if not clarified.*

Comment: thank you, I believe you are correct in that I should have indicated "neutral" (off the timer labeling) and not "common"

Answer (score 1):

Your timer has seven wires (Red, Yellow, Black White, Brown Gray Blue).  It requires two GFI circuits (let's call them A and B) one of which must have a neutral wire extended to the timer.

Blue, Gray, Brown all provide *switched power* from one hot leg of A.  Yellow provides *switched power* from one hot leg of B.  The other hot leg of each circuit gets patched through directly to the device without switching.   That's it, that's the whole story.  You can do this.  The unswitched Hot from circuit A is called "common" because it is common to three functions: Hi, Low, and Antifreeze.   There is nothing special about it that you need to provide.  It's one of the hots.

Both circuits need two-pole GFI breakers, both breakers will provide and handle neutral for 120V, and so long as one of your cables has the third (white) wire, your timer can take advantage of it.

You have what you need, you're good to go, don't worry about the label "common".

There are some electricians here who believe two-pole GFI breakers generate false trips when the neutral is actually used.   That may be true but you don't have much choice.  The timer isn't wired to accept a separate 120V circuit.   Take my advice: **Don't regard any trip as false.  Most of the time you're wrong, and there is in fact a ground fault.  Find it.**

[image]

Note: This diagram would be clearer *without* the useless label, "common".  It provides nothing but confusion.  It also could easily have been arranged so no wires cross over.  It was probably drawn by an intern with two weeks experience.  :(

Comment: The more I look at that diagram, the less respect I have for the person who drew it. God Bless every electrician who wired this thing successfully after looking at this.  :).    The 3 groupings of the wires at the top follow no pattern, make no sense, and add nothing but confusion.

Answer (score -1):

Your timer is a two pole switch, the common (netural) is required to power the clock motor. Your 220V wires come to the timer, connect to the common contacts, the two wires for the motor connect to the NO contacts of the timer. Since the timer already powered with 220 and has a common all you need to do is connect the two 220V output wires to the pump and of course the equipment ground.

Comment: Explain how 220 or 240 has a common because in the US this is 2 hots and no common, the reason multi wire branch circuits have gone out of fashion is the 120 v  works but now make it 240 and a neutral load the breaker can’t figure out if there is an imbalance so it trips.

Comment: It was working so it had to have the common to start with. The other alternative would be to change to a 220V clock motor if available.

Comment: Read again new pump we don’t know what changed in the past a grounded pump did not require GFCI so that may be new also.

Comment: @EdBeal On a PC go to the [Amazon page](https://www.amazon.com/Intermatic-RC2343PT-Timer/dp/B0039Q7ORO) and photo 2 clearly shows the instructions pasted on the label.  **The label uses "Common" in a very particular way**, and they are not referring to "Neutral" - they refer to that too.  They seem to use "common" akin to how 3-way switches and "2 switch 1 gang" switches use it.

Comment: Timer and pump are new and have not been previously installed.  To clarify I am doing advance research to ensure I have the correct equipment, before pump and timer are eventually installed correctly by a licensed electrician. I am assuming there would be 2 hots and a ground going from the 20a GFI tandem breaker to the timer (no white wires). But since there is not a white leg from the tandem breaker, and since the timer requires a white wire to complete the power circuit to the clock (and the air switch?), I was thinking that I simply have the wrong type of timer to match to the 240v pump.

Comment: That helps and the reason for my comments any leakage or load on the ground in excess 5ma will trip the GFCI and I am a licensed electrician the reason's for the comment , but only challenging me gets up votes so good luck

Comment: thanks Ed, based on my research, I think your point is accurate, any imbalance caused by interconnected equipment (other than the pump) will trigger the GFI breaker

Comment: Update on research to assist my electrician to wire 3 pool devices:
Intermatic RC2343PT timer (blower/freeze protection NOT used) 
Homeline 2-pole 20A 120/240 GFI 60Hz circuit breaker (two hots + neutral) 
Pentair 1.5 HP 230v 2-spd pump model#340043    
Wiring assumptions a) breaker neutral to timeclock white; b) one breaker hot to timeclock black; c) other breaker hot to pump T#1 per pump diagram; d) breaker ground to pump/timeclock g's; e) timeclock blue (hi-spd) to pump T#2 (per pump diagram); f) timeclock gray (lo-spd) to pump T#3/4 per pump diagram. Errors? Mixed info if GFI needed?